# How to move a QVBoxLayout with QPushButtons 50px to the top?

Tags: qt, qlayout, qvboxlayout

How can i move a QVBoxLayout with several QPushButtons 50px to the top?

This is my code. I tried this->adjustSize(), this->repaint(), but it doesn't move.

```
// get current geometry
QRect geo = ui->VBoxLayout->geometry();

// apply geometry, but substract 50px from y() to move it to the top
ui->VBoxLayout->setGeometry(
    QRect(geo.x(), geo.y() - 50, geo.width(), geo.height())
);
```

Comment: [add a spacing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addSpacing) as the first widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QVBoxLayout is not moveable standalone.
The solution is to embedded the QVBoxLayout into a QWidget of the same size (ui->VBoxLayout inside ui->RightSideWidget). The QWidget is moveable with move().

```
QRect geoWidget = ui->RightSideWidget->geometry();
ui->RightSideWidget->move(geoWidget.x(), geoWidget.y() - 50);
```